# iOS JSON parsing from web to a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I'm experiencing a problem with my code but I'm not sure why it's doing this. It's just giving me an error saying JSON Error. The UITableView never gets filled with anything. I'm not very experienced with iOS, so any help is appreciated.

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  Westmount Procrastinator
//
//  Created by Saleem on 10/25/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Saleem Al-Zanoon. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *fullURL = @"********";
    NSURL *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url2];
    [_webView loadRequest:requestObj];

    self.title = @"News";

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"****************"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];    //  NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://salespharma.net/westmount/get_all_products.php"];
  //  NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
 //   NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
 //   NSError * error;
//    NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
//    NSLog(@"%@",json);
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData
{
    [data appendData:theData];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    NSArray *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:NULL];
    //news = [responseDict objectAtIndex:0];
    // [mainTableView reloadData];
    if ([responseDict isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        news = responseDict;
        [mainTableView reloadData];
    } else {
        // Looks like here is some part of the problem but I don't know why.
        NSLog(@"JSON Error.");

        UIAlertView *errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Could not contact server!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [errorView show];

    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    UIAlertView *errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"The download could not complete - please make sure you're connected to either 3G or Wi-Fi." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorView show];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}

- (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [news count];
}

NSString *_getString(id obj)
{
    return [obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] ? obj : nil;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = _getString([[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Issue"]);
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = _getString([[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"]);

    return cell;
}
   @end
```

How the JSON looks on the internet:

```
    {

   "Issues":[
      {
         "Issue":"2",
         "Link":"google.com",
         "Name":"Ios Test"
      },
      {
         "Issue":"3",
         "Link":"Yahoo",
         "Name":"iOS test 2"
      }
   ],
   "success":1
}
```

Edit: sorry for not being clear in my question, The app does not crash but fails to load the data into the database in the log it puts this up:

```
2013-10-26 10:26:41.670 Westmount Procrastinator[2490:70b] JSON Error.
2013-10-26 10:26:41.671 Westmount Procrastinator[2490:70b] Server Data: 
{"Issues":[{"Issue":"2","Link":"google.com","Name":"Ios Test"}],"success":1}
```

The goal of the application to contact a database download a list of Issues of a newspaper then list them in the list view.. Then allowing the user to click on the issues and download them.

Edit I added more to the JSON to help explain.

Comment: Hello, please provide more details so that your question can be better answered. You should provide details like: the exact error message / crash log, the line on which the app crashed, only provide relevant code (not all of your code), and please explain in more detail what you're trying to do and what you're really asking. The StackOverflow community is not here to debug your programs for you, but we are here to help - so please make it more clear as to what you're asking and provide more details.

Comment: Are you sure this is what the JSON in your app actually looks like? What exactly is in the data object you get back from the server? You can print it out easily using: `NSLog(@"Server Data: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);`

Comment: I have edited the question adding more info, thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your sample JSON structure it does not appear to be a NSArray. It is NSDictionary instead. So, while you are parsing JSON data save it in NSDictionary and not in NSArray. Also, change your IF condition afterwards.

Importantly, if your tableview is reading data from an NSArray of NSDictionaries then I would say put this NSDictionary into an NSArray and pass it to table view. Also, check from server side what is the output in case they are multiple dictionaries in which you need to handle accordingly. So essentially there are couple of more lines you need to induce here or else ask data provider (server side) to send NSArray in all cases.

```
NSDictionary *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:NULL];
if ([responseDict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    NSArray *tableArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:responseDict[@"Issues"]];
}
```

**Now use tableArray to populate your table.**

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, in my PHP code that actually displays the JSON is seems to be a Array.
    `$Issues = array();`

Comment: But the sample JSON you put in your question does not seems to be an NSArray. You might want to check that once. Try with the code I shared and you should get a NSDictionary from your JSON.

Comment: Alright using the code your provided fixed one issue but caused another, the log is clear now so it does not complain but the table stays empty and Xcode warns me: `Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSArray *' from 'NSDictionary *'`
So I tried changing the type news from NSarray to NSdictionary. and it gives out the error: `No visible @interface for 'NSDictionary' declares the selector 'objectAtIndex:'` for this line of code:`cell.textLabel.text = _getString([[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Issue"]);`

Comment: I knew this and I warn you about this in my answer. So, your table view is expecting a NSArray and not NSDictionary. You need to follow my answer word by word.

Comment: Again I have been investigating I'm using the same database that I used for the android version of the app and it seems as though it's a NSArray. In the android version it's looping through the array and getting the Issues.... So that leads me to believe it's an array.   I can't seem to get it to work what so ever if I try NSDictionary or NSArray any further suggestions/solutions?

Comment: Can you please try once by adding your response dictionary into NSArray and use that for table drawing: NSArray *responseArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:responseDict];

Comment: I have just tried that, my table is still empty but I have no more warnings or errors.

Comment: I have updated my answer above. Use this and you should be good to go.

Comment: Issues is definitely an array, but @M0NKEYRASH the response itself is not. It's a dictionary, clearly shown by the JSON. Instead, just get the issues array out of it: `NSArray* issues = responseDict[@"Issues"];`

Comment: Using some of your tips and some trial and error I finally got it working, thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Issues is an array of dictionaries, so you should ask for the dictionary at the `indexpath.row`, then use `objectForKey` to pull the appropriate value from that dictionary.

```
    NSDictionary *myDict = @{@"Issues": @[@{@"Issue": @"2",
                                            @"Link": @"google.com",
                                            @"Name": @"Ios Test"},
                                          @{@"Issue": @"3",
                                            @"Link": @"Yahoo",
                                            @"Name": @"iOS test 2"}],
                             @"success": @"1"};

    NSArray *issues = [myDict objectForKey:@"Issues"];

    [issues enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSLog(@"Issue: %@ Link: %@ Name: %@", [obj objectForKey:@"Issue"], [obj objectForKey:@"Link"], [obj objectForKey:@"Name"]);
    }];
```

Will return:

```
2013-10-26 16:42:43.572 Jsontest[43803:303] Issue: 2 Link: google.com Name: Ios Test
2013-10-26 16:42:43.573 Jsontest[43803:303] Issue: 3 Link: Yahoo Name: iOS test 2
```